# How to show rows with 0 without any records in database

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of record in my database and for data analysis, I need to show count of records for each day including days when I do not have any record, so result is `0`.

For example I have these records ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/397e6b/1/0)):

```
CREATE TABLE Tabs
    (`timestamp` varchar(10), `id` int)
;

INSERT INTO Tabs
    (`timestamp`, `id`)
VALUES
    ('2015-01-01', 1),
    ('2015-01-01', 2),
    ('2015-01-02', 3),
    ('2015-01-02', 4),
    ('2015-01-02', 5),
    ('2015-01-04', 6),
    ('2015-01-05', 7),
    ('2015-01-05', 8)
;
```

When I use this query:

```
SELECT `timestamp`, COUNT(*)
FROM Tabs
GROUP BY `timestamp`
```

I get ths result:

```
timestamp   COUNT(*)
2015-01-01  2
2015-01-02  3
2015-01-04  1
2015-01-05  2
```

But I need `2015-01-03` too with `0`, so correct output for me is:

```
timestamp   COUNT(*)
2015-01-01  2
2015-01-02  3
2015-01-02  0
2015-01-04  1
2015-01-05  2
```

How can I realize it please?

Comment: you need to use a calendar table and then do a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: That column needs to be `DATE`, not a `varchar(10)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you know the `date_start` and `date_end` and you won't work on more than 1000 days although it can be extended.

This example works with these values:

```
SET @date_start := CAST('20150101' as date);
SET @date_end := CAST('20150108' as date);
```

Below queries return each day between `@date_start` (2015-01-01) and `@date_end`(2015-01-08). This is similar to a calendar. The full list of days can then be `LEFT JOIN` to the list of available days in the table.

#### Using `SELECT ... UNION ALL ...`

```
SELECT @date := date_add(@date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) as date
FROM (
    SELECT 0 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
    UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  )d10, (
    SELECT 0 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
    UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9   
  )d100, (
    SELECT 0 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
    UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9   
  ) d1000
  , (SELECT @date := date_add(@date_start, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) v
WHERE @date < @date_end
;
```

#### Output:

```
date
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-04
2015-01-05
2015-01-06
2015-01-07
2015-01-08
```

- Each inner `SELECT ... UNION ALL ...` returns 10 rows from 0 to 9
- This `SELECT` is used and `CROSS JOIN` 3 times and returns 1000 rows (10*10*10) from day 0 to day 999
- Because 1 is added to @date, it means that it can return up to 1000 consecutives days
- You can work on 10.000 days if you add one more `SELECT ... UNION ALL ...` and so on or on 100 if the third join is removed
- You can then LEFT JOIN this query with your table

#### Using a view

It is probably easier to create a view with numbers from 0 to 9 and CROSS JOIN it 3 times or create 1 single view from 0 to 999:

```
CREATE VIEW viewDec As
  SELECT 0 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
;    

SELECT @date := date_add(@date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) as date
FROM viewDec d10, viewDec d100, viewDec d1000
    , (SELECT @date := date_add(@date_start, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) v
WHERE @date < @date_end
;
```

- You can work on 10.000 days by adding an extra `viewDec d10000` ...

#### Using an existing table

It is also possible to replace the `SELECT` or `VIEW` by an existing table with enough rows (1000 in this example):

```
SELECT @date := date_add(@date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) as date
FROM (SELECT 1 as n FROM table_with_over_1000_rows LIMIT 1000) t
    , (SELECT @date := date_add(@date_start, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) v
WHERE @date < @date_end
;
```

#### Full query (using viewDec)

```
SELECT `date`, count(t.`id`)
FROM (
  SELECT @date := date_add(@date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) as date
  FROM viewDec d10, viewDec d100, viewDec d1000
    , (SELECT @date := date_add(@date_start, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) v
  WHERE @date < @date_end  
) d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `id`, `timestamp`
    FROM Tabs
    /* WHERE sensor = 10 */
) t
    ON d.`date` = t.`timestamp`
GROUP BY d.`date`
;
```

In this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12b662/1) `timestamp` has been replaced by a type date column.

#### Output:

```
date        count(t.`id`)
2015-01-01  2
2015-01-02  3
2015-01-03  0
2015-01-04  1
2015-01-05  2
2015-01-06  0
2015-01-07  0
2015-01-08  0
```

Comment: One thing yet please. What form of select will when I need restrict, that I need get only records with "0" values for some sensor from my database, for example:
`SELECT timestamp, COUNT(*)
FROM Tabs
WHERE Tabs.sensor = "10"
GROUP BY timestamp`

If I use it, it does not show values with "0"...

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you need Group By ... Having count()  = 10 ?

Comment: No, I need apply this select only for records that satisfy the condition that their Tabs.sensor ID is 10. After I need apply the same condition for records that is ID (Tabs.sensor) for example 5 and etc. Sensor is column in table Tabs that identify my sensors. And I need show records with 0 only for some these sensors (for example for sensor that Tabs.sensor = "10")...

Comment: I  move `Tabs t` to a subquery where a `where` clause can be added. another option without a subquery is `sensor=10 or sensor is null`